# limit of sum defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}, n\ge1$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n (x_n-n-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{5}{24}$.

What I've done:it's easy to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n-n)=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: How is that "easy"? Show your work so that, perhaps, we can see something to help.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659672) question.

Comment: @Lucian This gives the limit of $x_n-n$ for $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}-1$, but not the one actually asked -- is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Expand the square root in a taylor series to three terms, to get $1+k/2n^2 -k^2/8 n^4+ k^3/16 n^6,$ then sum.

The sum of the $1$s gives you $n$. The sum of $k/n^2$ gives $n(n+1)/4n^2,$ the sum of $k^2/n^4$ gives you $(1+n)(2+n)/48 n^3,$ and the next term is $O(1/n^2).$

Comment: It may be obvious, but the fact that there is a sum of $n$ (which goes to infinity) different $O(\cdot)$'s, each of them coming with its "own personal asymptotics" (constant, etc.) should at least be considered -- or, say, mentioned. In the end, it's fine here, but that sort of overlook leads to mistakes in quite a few other scenarii.

Comment: @ClementC. This is basically Fubini's theorem (since everything converges absolutely), I agree that this is something that the OP should be aware of.

Comment: (Yes -- I am not concerned about correctness here -- only about the fact that these things can be misleading if not thought of in general.)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is wrong, but I would like to know why.

$$n(x_n-n-\frac{1}{4})=n \sum (\sqrt{(1+\frac{k}{n^2})}-(1+\frac{1}{4n}))$$

$$=n \sum \frac{(1+\frac{k}{n^2})-(1+\frac{1}{4n} )^2}{
\sqrt{(1+\frac{k}{n^2})}+1+\frac{1}{4n}
}$$

$$=n \sum \frac{
\frac{k}{n^2} - \frac{1}{16n^2} -\frac{1}{2n}}{
\sqrt{(1+\frac{k}{n^2})}+1+\frac{1}{4n}
}
$$

Since $$
\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}+1+\frac{1}{4n} \leq \sqrt{(1+\frac{k}{n^2})}+1+\frac{1}{4n}  \leq \sqrt{(1+\frac{n}{n^2})}+1+\frac{1}{4n}
$$, 
and they have the same limit as $n$ tends to infinity, we will apply sandwich theorem to the sum later.

Now,

$$n \sum (\frac{k}{n^2} - \frac{1}{16n^2} -\frac{1}{2n} )$$

$$=n (\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} - \frac{1}{16n} -\frac{1}{2} )$$

$$=(\frac{n+1}{2} - \frac{1}{16} -\frac{n}{2} )$$

$$=(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{16})=7/16$$

So even after dividing two, because of the denominator, it is $7/32$...

Comment: It **is** puzzling. I did try this as well, and got the same answer as yours — which indeed is wrong. The eventual explanation I could find is the following: what you have is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k,n)}{g(k,n)}$, and you can write that for all $n$ and every $1\leq k\leq n$ $$g_1(n) \leq g(k,n) \leq g_2(n)$$ with $g_1(n),g_2(n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 2$. To apply the squeeze theorem, which is very tempting, it would be sufficient to have for all $n$ **and** $1\leq k\leq n$ the inequality $$\frac{f(k,n)}{g_1(n)} \leq \frac{f(k,n)}{g(k,n)} \leq \frac{f(k,n)}{g_2(n)}.$$

Comment: But this inequality does **not** hold for all $1\leq k\leq n$: you can check, the sign of $f(k,n)$ changes for $k\simeq \frac{n}{2}$, and therefore the direction of the inequality changes as well... In other terms, you cannot apply the squeeze theorem, since because of cancellations (due to the change of sign of the summands) the inequality $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k,n)}{g_1(n)} \leq\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{f(k,n)}{g(k,n)} \leq\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{f(k,n)}{g_2(n)}$$ is **not** true.

Comment: (as for some $k$'s you have $\frac{f(k,n)}{g_1(n)} \leq  \frac{f(k,n)}{g(k,n)} \leq \frac{f(k,n)}{g_2(n)}$ but for some others you have $\frac{f(k,n)}{g_1(n)} \geq  \frac{f(k,n)}{g(k,n)} \geq \frac{f(k,n)}{g_2(n)}$: the inequalities summand by summand cannot be added.)

Comment: Note that this technique **does** work to get the limit $1/4$ of $x_n-n$: in this case, all the summands stay positive and things add up. (also, +1 for the approach, which is a natural one, and brings a rather subtle issue.)

Comment: @ClementC. Oh yes you are right. $f$ not always positive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using that $\frac{k}{n^2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$, one can use the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$, $$\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + o(x^2)$$ when $x\to 0$:
$$\begin{align}
x_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}
= \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{2n^2}-\frac{k^2}{8n^4}+o\left(\frac{k^2}{n^4}\right)\right)
\\
&= n+ \frac{1}{2n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{1}{8n^4}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= n+ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{1}{8n^4}\cdot\frac{2n^3}{6} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= n+ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{6}{24n} - \frac{1}{24n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= n+ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{5}{24n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}$$
giving you $n(x_n - n - \frac{1}{4}) = \frac{5}{24} + o(1)$.

**Note:** Now, while the above is a valid and legit method, one should stop and at least consider why the manipulation and summation of the $o(\cdot)$'s is indeed acceptable. (Specifically: while it's implicit, what each $o(\cdot)$'s is taken with regard to? $n\to\infty$, or $\frac{k}{n}\to0$ each for a different $k$? And why is it still OK?)

Comment: Excuse the comment, but isn't this answer the same as the first one above? I'm new here and I still get confused with when to give complete answers, hints, when to repeat answers, etc. Thank you.

Comment: @Joanpemo I was typing while the other answer appeared. The idea is the same, although I detailed quite a bit more; also, the main point (unaddressed in both, but pointed out in my answer) is *why* doing a Taylor expansion such as this one is valid. There is a sum of $n$ (which goes to infinity) different $o()$ or $O()$'s, each possibly with their "own hidden constant": typically, this requires at least a bit of thinking to argue that adding an unbounded number of negligible terms is fine.